# linking to jqueryUI tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, hyperlink, jquery-ui-tabs

So i am still having issues with this. but now at least have an online version that i can show you..

http://dev.morrisonsports.com.au/products/zipvit-sport#tabs-3

as you can see.. when you use the # tag to link to any but the first tab (because its so long) the user ends up at the bottom of the page.. rather than at where the tab titles are..

i have given up on what i was trying to do before (getting it to link into the tab to content there) and decided if i can at least get it to link to the tab and stay at the top of the tabs (where the tab titles are) ill be happy..

I am really hoping the solution doesnt lie in $_POST or $_GET data as using forms to do this will probably not work so nicely with the JS degradation..

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is how it is supposed to work. #tab3 is linking to that tab's contents, not the tab headers where the tabs are. Therefor the browser brings you to the content. Make your browser very short and you can see it is bringing you to the top of your tab content - not the bottom of the page.

Comment: the #tab-3 anchor is at the top of each tab's content.. but the content isnt moved into tabs until after the page loads.. as the JS files are loaded in the footer (as per accessibility standards).. problem is.. the #tab-3 anchor on page load start isnt in a tab yet.. and is still in a long line of divs one after another.. even though it is display:none;.. so it tries to move to there (bottom of the page) and then the tabs load.. realise #tab-3 has been called and shows that tab as active.. but the page is still looking where #tab-3 was when the page load started..

Answer (score 0):

ok so upon posting my comment to themerlinproject above.. it occurred to me that the javascript was looking at the #tab-3 anchor as an indicator to show tab-3 
(which is a

```
     <div>
```

not an

```
      <a>
```

)

but the browser looks for

```
    <a name="tab-3">
```

independent of the javascript.. and failing an a seems to be looking for the div.. so i just put the following code.. ABOVE the tab menu section

```
            <a name="tabs-1"></a>
            <a name="tabs-2"></a>
            <a name="tabs-3"></a>
            <a name="tabs-4"></a>
            <a name="tabs-5"></a>
```

and now the browser links to the < a>'s and the javascript links to the divs :D

Thanks for the flash though themerlinproject